# Change product price and stock in product view page when cache is enabled in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, stock

I have tried to update the custom price and change stock for products by event/observer when the cache is enabled. But none of the events will work on full page cache in product view page.

Comment: Will be better if your post contain question. When enabled Varnish  fpc cache  php code do not running at all for cached pages

Comment: How then we change price for products on fly?

Comment: Only by using javascript.

Comment: @KAndy You are useless